# Why does the function of two database queries show me only the result of the first query?

Tags: php, mysql, function, prepared-statement

The output of the following shows me the result of the first query, but not the second. When I make the queries without function it works.

```
function builtFooter($catactive, $catlink)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT catid, catname_de AS name, catlink as link, extern, extlink FROM categories WHERE catactive=? AND catlink!=? ORDER BY catsort";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $catactive, $catlink);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($cat = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $resArr[] = $cat;
        echo '<h3><a href="' . $cat['link'] . '" title="' . $cat['name'] . ' bei $portalname">' . $cat['name'] . '</a></h3>';

        $cities = "SELECT COUNT(a.ad_id) AS ANZ,a.region, b.city, b.citylink FROM ads a, neueorte b WHERE a.zeigen=? AND a.gesperrt=? AND FIND_IN_SET(?, a.portale) AND a.catid=? AND b.po_id=a.region GROUP BY a.region ORDER BY ANZ DESC LIMIT 0,50";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($cities);
        $zeigen = 'ja';
        $gesperrt = 'no';
        $category = $cat['catid'];
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $zeigen, $gesperrt, $portalnumber, $category);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        while ($city = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $resArr[] = $city;
            echo ' ' . $city['city'] . ' <br />';
        }
    }
}

builtFooter('yes', 'markt');
```

Comment: You're overwriting the `$result` variable inside the loop, so in the second iteration of the outer `while`-loop, it will contain the results of the last query, not the initial. Avoid reusing variables inside the loop.

Comment: It still does not work.

Comment: What changes have you made and what exactly doesn't work? It's really hard to help here unless you post more info, like the db table schemas, example data, expected result from that data and what you're currently getting. If you've made changes to your code, then we need to see those changes as well, or we're just working in the dark here.

Answer (score 0):

This queries are working fine, and I get the result I want:

```
$catactive = 'yes';
$catlink = 'markt';
$sql = "SELECT catid, catname_de AS name, catlink as link, extern, extlink FROM categories WHERE catactive=? AND catlink!=? ORDER BY catsort";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $catactive, $catlink);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        while ($cat = $result->fetch_assoc()) {    
            $resArr[] = $cat;
           echo '<h3><a href="'.$cat['link'].'" title="'.$cat['name'].' bei $portalname">'.$cat['name'].'</a></h3>';
        
        $cities = "SELECT COUNT(a.ad_id) AS ANZ,a.region, b.city, b.citylink FROM ads a, neueorte b WHERE a.zeigen=? AND a.gesperrt=? AND FIND_IN_SET(?, a.portale) AND a.catid=? AND b.po_id=a.region GROUP BY a.region ORDER BY ANZ DESC LIMIT 0,50";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($cities); 
        $zeigen = 'ja';
        $gesperrt = 'no';
        $category = $cat['catid'];
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $zeigen, $gesperrt, $portalnumber, $category);
        $stmt->execute();
        $r = $stmt->get_result();
        while ($city = $r->fetch_assoc()) {    
            $resArr[] = $city;
            echo' '.$city['city'].' <br />';
        }
       }
```

But when I built a function, I do not get the results of the secode query:

```
function builtFooter($catactive,$catlink){
        global $conn;
            $sql = "SELECT catid, catname_de AS name, catlink as link, extern, extlink FROM categories WHERE catactive=? AND catlink!=? ORDER BY catsort";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $catactive, $catlink);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            while ($cat = $result->fetch_assoc()) {    
                $resArr[] = $cat;
               echo '<h3><a href="/sexkontakte/'.$cat['link'].'" title="'.$cat['name'].' bei $portalname">'.$cat['name'].'</a></h3>';
            
            $cities = "SELECT COUNT(a.ad_id) AS ANZ,a.region, b.city, b.citylink FROM ads a, neueorte b WHERE a.zeigen=? AND a.gesperrt=? AND FIND_IN_SET(?, a.portale) AND a.catid=? AND b.po_id=a.region GROUP BY a.region ORDER BY ANZ DESC LIMIT 0,50";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($cities); 
            $zeigen = 'ja';
            $gesperrt = 'no';
            $category = $cat['catid'];
            $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $zeigen, $gesperrt, $portalnumber, $category);
            $stmt->execute();
            $r = $stmt->get_result();
            while ($city = $r->fetch_assoc()) {    
                $resArr[] = $city;
                echo' '.$city['city'].' <br />';
    }
    }
       }
       builtFooter('yes','markt');
```

I have the tables categories, ads, neueorte. I want built footer links, so I want the categorie as a h3 tag and the cities grouped by city where ads are placed. I hope I made it right, I am new to this page.

Comment: Answers should be used only to post solutions to a question. To make updates to your question you can edit it.